# Reading from database file over network in visual basic, with no shared drives

Tags: vb.net, networking, odbc

The machine I'm trying to access is an industrial PC that serves as the interface for some PLC-automated equipment.  The computer creates a data record (an .mdb database) of the various machine settings so that they can be reviewed later if desired.  I've created an application in Visual Basic 2010 to display and sort that information once it's been copied from the machine to someone's laptop.

What I'd like to do, though, is allow the user to access the database from their laptop over the network; each PC has a static IP address on the customer's LAN.  Currently, we can use Teamviewer to transfer files, but I'd like to include that ability in my data viewing application.  Without changing any settings on the industrial PC (i.e. leaving the network file sharing alone, and avoiding installing any sort of SQL server software), how can I access this information?  The database files can get pretty large (40+ mb) so I'm trying to avoid any sort of FTP transfer, which would undoubtedly take forever.

The database is already set up on an ODBC connection (which is how the pc stores the PLC information in the database), and I suspect that this may be the key, but between my lack of any thorough understanding regarding networking and the internet's general distrust of ODBC (well earned, from what I've seen so far), I'm having a hard time finding any useful information.

If anyone could point me towards some useful tutorials, or give me a good place to start, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of luck. Think about it, if you could access the file, without sharing it, wouldn't that be a serious security problem?

What you can do: Use the always existing share \host\c$ to access the file. For that you'll need administrative privileges for the host.

But be aware: Even if this "works", it introduces problems:

1. It will be slow, because you are essentially copying 40MB over the wire over and over again
2. If you are not carefull, you might lock the *.mdb file while accessing it. Access Databases are not really meant to be accessed by multiple users/processes. That didn't prevented Microsoft to try to fake it. Todo so, a *.ldb (L as in Lock) file will be created, to signal other processes the file is locked.

Tldr: Don't do it.